# Tomcat can't start with SpringBoot war. Missing Class exception LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a SpringBoot2.2.5 That runs perfectly when running standalone. It is a REST app that serves both json and XML. Once we deploy it to one of our tomcat servers (Tomcat 8.5.38) it fails (see error below).

I searched all over to try and find the class in question but have no idea where it would be or what jar I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
16-Apr-2020 17:23:23.365 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vservice]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/l10n/LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(SpringWebApplicationInitializer.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.l10n.LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1185)
    ... 14 more
```

Here is the dependency tree for the app:

`

```
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
    [INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.11-java7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.6.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.6.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.6.7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring5:jar:2.29.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.29.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
    [INFO] |  \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
    [INFO] |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.6.7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.7:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
    [INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.46:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:provided
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.31:provided
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.31:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.31:provided
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
    [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
    [INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:jar:2.9.2:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.xml:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
    [INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.1:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
    [INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
    [INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
    [INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
    [INFO] +- com.valspar:valspar-common-utils:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
    [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.4:compile
    [INFO] +- com.sherwin:vservices_api:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.16.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- oracle:ojdbc:jar:10.1.0.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
    [INFO] \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
    [INFO]    \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile`
```

Comment: Your dependencies have both starter-jersey and starter-web, they could be an alternative to each others, do you have to mixed them in your project?

Comment: Yes I do. It is used for exception handlers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232117/tomcat-9-cant-load-spring-boot-application for solution